# Android Studio code copy and paste question

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, comments

I have a bunch of code with some lines commented out, and I'd like to copy all of the code including the comments that android studio automatically adds.

I've tried various combinations of ctrl+c with shift, alt etc, but when pasting into notepad (for example) only the code shows and not the automatic comments.

For example after a closing bracket, AS often adds `//Container` to the lines automatically.  However, when if I add similar comments manually, those do get copied. Is there a way to copy the auto comments?

EDIT: I tried to give this question a better Title, but StackOverflow really didn't like any variation on "How do I copy and paste commented code in Android Studio?"
Also edited as I didn't realise my own manually written comments were being copied when I asked this question.

Comment: Is the code all in one file?

Comment: Ah, ok, further investigation shows that comments I put in get copied, but auto comments do not (such as `// Container` after a closing bracket and comma).  Sorry, I'm very new to coding.  I'll edit my original question.

Comment: try ctrl + a to select all and then copy. does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  That does select all the code, but still doesn't include the comments that were automatically added by Android Studio.  It's not a big issue, and nothing is technically wrong, so don't worry too much, I was just hoping that there would be a quick way to do it rather than type those comments myself to my reference document!  Thank you for the help though!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are just hints added by the IDE (Intellij + dart plugin), not actual code (comments). The dart plugin calls them closing labels.

Comment: Ahh so no way to copy them then, as they don't technically exist?  I can't select them individually, but they do get selected when dragging multiple lines or with ctrl+a.  I was hoping there would be a way to 'flatten' what's in the code window, so to speak, so I could copy it, but I guess not.  Thanks for the response though!  :)